# publishing sveltekit to digitalocean-- need to add strict : false, where do I add this flag

Tags: sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

I'm attempting to publish my first sveltekit app to digitalocean. I used adapter-node but as per [doc](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#options-strict) :

By default, adapter-static checks that either all pages and endpoints (if any) of your app were prerendered, or you have the fallback option set. This check exists to prevent you from accidentally publishing an app where some parts of it are not accessible, because they are not contained in the final output. If you know this is ok (for example when a certain page only exists conditionally), you can set strict to false to turn off this check.

Where do I add that strict : false flag??